# ¿Cómo obtengo el valor de una variable php al value de un elemento html con javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

El archivo de php trae un conjunto de registros desde la bd, en el código, el while lee todos los registros para mostrarlos en una tabla. Esa tabla tiene un botón para dar de baja una propiedad. Se puede ver en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Error que muestra la consola del navegador]

Este es el código del While:

```
                  $cursor_propiedad = $conexion->query($sql_propiedad);
                  while ($propiedad = $cursor_propiedad->fetch()) {
                  ?>
                   <tr>
                     <td><?php echo $propiedad["cod_propiedad"]; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo utf8_encode($propiedad["nombre_tipo_propiedad"]); ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo utf8_encode($propiedad["nombre_tipo_operacion"]); ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo utf8_encode($propiedad["nombre_comuna"]); ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo utf8_encode($propiedad["nombre_sector"]); ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $propiedad["simbologia_tipo_valor"] . mostrarPrecio($propiedad["valor_propiedad"]); ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $propiedad["observacion_propietario"]; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $propiedad["nombre_persona"]; ?></td>

                     <td><?php echo $propiedad["fecha_captacion_propiedad"]; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $propiedad["cantidad_superficie_total_propiedad"]; ?></td>
                     <td class="center">
                       <a href="editar-propiedad.php?id_propiedad=<?php echo $propiedad["id_propiedad"]; ?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs expanded">Editar</a>
                       <?php
                        if ($propiedad["is_hidden"] ==  0) {
                        ?>

                         <a href="#open-modal" id="botonDarBaja" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs expanded">Dar baja</a>
                         <input id="valorIdPropiedad" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $propiedad["cod_propiedad"]; ?>">
                         <p> Valor: <?php echo $propiedad["cod_propiedad"]; ?> </p>
                         <!--<a href="../php/esconder_propiedad.php?id_propiedad=<?php echo $propiedad["id_propiedad"]; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs expanded" >Dar baja</a> -->
                         <?php
                          if ($_COOKIE["id_cuenta"] != 13) {
                          ?>
                           <?php
                            if ($propiedad["is_oferta"] ==  0) {
                            ?>
                             <a href="../php/ofertar_propiedad.php?id_propiedad=<?php echo $propiedad["id_propiedad"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs expanded">Oferta</a>
                           <?php
                            } else {
                            ?>
                             <a href="../php/quitar_oferta_propiedad.php?id_propiedad=<?php echo $propiedad["id_propiedad"]; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs expanded">Quitar oferta</a>
                           <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                         <?php
                          }
                          ?>
                       <?php
                        } else {
                        ?>
                         <a href="../php/mostrar_propiedad.php?id_propiedad=<?php echo $propiedad["id_propiedad"]; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs expanded">Activar</a>
                       <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                       <?php
                        $sql_validar = "SELECT * FROM documentos_propiedades WHERE cod_propiedad=" . $propiedad["cod_propiedad"];

                        $cursor_validar = $conexion->query($sql_validar);
                        if (!$validar = $cursor_validar->rowCount()) {
                          $validar = 0;
                        }

                        if ($validar != 0) {
                        ?>
                         <a target="_BLANK" class="btn btn-success btn-xs expanded" href="../php/mostrar_documento_propiedad.php?cod_propiedad=<?php echo $propiedad["cod_propiedad"]; ?>"> Ver documento </a>
                       <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                     </td>
                   </tr>
                 <?php
                  }
                  ?>
```

Y, específicamente, esta es la línea de donde quiero rescatar el valor del código de la propiedad en el javascript:

```
<input id="valorIdPropiedad" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $propiedad["cod_propiedad"]; ?>">
```

Si aprecian la imagen, el código lo puedo rescatar en la etiqueta 'p', por lo tanto, está bien la referencia a la variable.

Sin embargo, en el javascript el valor viene nulo. Aquí el código javascript:

```
<script>
 $("#botonDarBaja").click(function() {
       var nombreBtnDarBaja = document.getElementById('valorIdPropiedad').value;
       document.getElementById('idProp').value = nombreBtnDarBaja;
     });
</script>
```

¿Qué estaré haciendo mal?

Comment: Ororok, esta expresión `document.getElementById('idProp')` está devolviendo null. Debes revisar por qué no existe el elemento #idProp cuando das click sobre #botonDarBaja.

Comment: Aparte de lo dicho por @tiomno, estás creando todo en un ciclo y vas a tener dos o más elementos con la misma ID y esta debe ser única, de lo contrario te va a provocar errores.